# Swift: Segmentation fault 11 on importing files to bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

[image]I have this legacy code base written in objective C, I recently tried to incorporate swift, I made all the necessary changes for using swift like bridging headers and build settings. When I add new objective C files and import them to bridging header everything works fine, but when I try to import old objective c classes the code stops compiling stating Segmentation fault.

Can you please suggest some possible solution?

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: Is that old ObjC code or frameworks are compatible with 64-bit?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon its 64 bit compatible

Comment: can you post the error screen?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon done

Comment: is bitcode enable?

Comment: @SohilR.Memon nope

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this, go to Build Settings -> Swift Compiler - Code generation, set Optimisation Level to None.

[image]

Hope this may help you.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, this issue was due to CocoaPods. My version of CocoaPods was too high for a few of the pods I was using. Switched back to an older version of CocoaPods, pod update, clean + build.