# Swift - Command failed due to signal: Segmentation fault: 11 when build in configuration Release

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I'm trying to compile a project then the Xcode said that.
I hope to receive the answers for these concerns, here are the situation:

- Xcode 8.3.2
- Swift 3.0
- All Frameworks are built via Carthage (Exclude Fabric & Crashlitics) [image]
- When I build in Debug configuration everything are ok, but when I change to configuration Release then the compile always failed.
- I tried to change the Optimization Level to Fast, Single-File Optimization[-O] then the Xcode works well and I also can archive to ipa file.

I have some concerns, could you please review ?
 + How do I completely resolve this problem and keep the default Optimization Level value for configuration Release ?
 + If I change Optimization Level value to Fast, Single-File Optimization[-O], could I submit the binary file to App store review ? Does it violet Apple's tos ?

Thank you,

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36996562/swift-segmentation-fault-11-on-importing-files-to-bridging-header/36999463#36999463

Comment: like I said, 
I tried to change the Optimization Level to Fast, Single-File Optimization[-O] then the Xcode works well and I also can archive to ipa file.

I'm looking for a better solution and verify the current solution :)

Answer (score 0):

you can get this error when the compiler gets too confused about what's going on in your code. I noticed you have a number of what appear to be functions nested within functions. You might try commenting out some of that at a time to see if the error goes away. That way you can zero in on the problem area. You can't use breakpoints because it's a compile time error, not a run time error.

And it might be possible that you have used a custom frameworks so just remove that custom framework which shows error